# An IdP/STS for SaaS providers, where the SaaS customer does his own user management?

Tags: saas, user-management, federated-identity, identity-management

(This question is not about programming, but about how to *avoid* doing any programming.  Also, lots of terminology in here-- I'm assuming someone with an answer will already know what they mean.)

Background: I'm working on single sign-on in an environment with 'federated identity'.  We have several products that are federation-aware (using, e.g., WS-Federation or SAML protocol, implemented with, e.g., WIF on .NET and Fedlet on Java), and they are offered to customers using a SaaS model.  Many of those customers don't have their own store of usernames/passwords, so they will not run an "identity provider" themselves.

Question: Is there a product out there that

- can be installed at the SaaS provider;
- plays the role of an IdP/STS (i.e., identity provider in a federated enviroment) to the SaaS-provided applications;
- has its own username/password store, separately for each SaaS customer ("tenant");
- allows the SaaS customer to do his own user management, without requiring assistance from the SaaS provider.

(We could build this ourselves, e.g., as a custom STS on top of WIF with user admin screens, but we're trying to avoid that.  It's not really our core business.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we did not find a product that fulfills all these requirements.

What we decided on was to use [AD FS 2.0](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2%28WS.10%29.aspx) as the SaaS IdP/STS, store usernames/passwords in AD (making the SaaS customer name part of the username), and [customize the AD FS sign-in page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895356.aspx) linked to a custom web application for user management and user self-service.

Comment: Any changes to this answer after 2 years?
(I have the same question)

Comment: @The_Smallest No, this is still the way in which we do things-- but I'm not involved anymore in things related to federated identity and single sign-on, and I don't know of more recent research.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [Google app engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) ?
They support SAML, so you can use them as your Idp.

Comment: That wouldn't fit the bill, since we want to run this IdP/STS in our own SaaS environment.